# Howto install distribute for Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, pywin32, distribute

I am trying to install [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) using ActivePython 3.1.2 on Windows.

Running `python distribute_setup.py` as described on the cheese shop give me:

> No setuptools distribution found
>   running install
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "setup.py", line 177, in 
>   scripts = scripts,
>   File "C:\Dev\Python_x86\3.1\lib\distutils\core.py", line 149, in setup
>   dist.run_commands()
>   File "C:\Dev\Python_x86\3.1\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 919, in run_commands
>   self.run_command(cmd)
>   File "C:\Dev\Python_x86\3.1\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 938, in run_command
>   cmd_obj.run()
>   File "build\src\setuptools\command\install.py", line 73, in run
>   self.do_egg_install()
>   File "build\src\setuptools\command\install.py", line 82, in do_egg_install
>   easy_install = self.distribution.get_command_class('easy_install')
>   File "build\src\setuptools\dist.py", line 361, in get_command_class
>   self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
>   File "build\src\pkg_resources.py", line 1953, in load
>   entry = **import**(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['**name**'])
>   File "build\src\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 16, in 
>   from setuptools.sandbox import run_setup
>   File "build\src\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 164, in 
>   fromlist=['**name**']).**file**)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '**file**'
>   Something went wrong during the installation.
>   See the error message above.

Is there possibly an unknown dependency that I'm missing?

Downloading the source tarball and executing `python setup.py install` produces the exact same output.

**Edit**: Added the full stack trace for running the installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently the python.org version of Python3 is different from the ActiveState version of Python3. (You should file a bug to someone (I'm not sure to whom))

The fix I have (I'm not sure of all the repercussions)

Download:

http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.12.tar.gz#md5=5a52e961f8d8799d243fe8220f9d760e

and then extracting it and modify:
distribute-0.6.12\setuptools\sandbox.py:165
from:

```
except ImportError:
```

to

```
except (ImportError, AttributeError):
```

that will silence the error and allow you to run:

python setup.py install

It took me awhile to find a package from http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=533&show=all that would *actually* install on either version of Python3. "files" was the first package, and since it installed I am pretty sure that easy_install is working for both copies of Python3.

...hope it works! (That's all I can help you with)

Comment: It looks like you *might* get the same error, but if you do can you put up the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes, i have already tried that and I get the same error. I'll add the full stack trace to the question if that will help.

Comment: Thanks for the stack trace... I was looking at it and decided to just try installing Python3 on a virtual machine I already had setup. This was a clean copy of Python3 from python.org. The install went fine, and now I am testing why there is a difference between Active Python and the one already tested.

Answer (score 3):

this is a bug with Distribute http://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/issue/151 ... it should be fixed by next release (0.6.13). It is only reproducible with PyWin32 installed; and ActivePython comes bundled with PyWin32.